# Changing inline javascript with Perl variables into a function

Tags: javascript, perl

I currently have a `select` tag with an inline onChange property like this:

```
<select id="owner_sel" name="owner" 
   <% print ' style="display: none"' if(!$user->has_permission($task->cid, $PERMISSION_CHANGE_OWNER)); %>
   onChange="if(!this.selectedIndex == 0) {
                if(this.form.state_id.value == <%= $STATE_NEW %>) {
                   this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_ASSIGNED %>
                }
             } else {
                this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_NEW %>
             }">

    <option></option>
    <% 
          foreach my $h (@sorted_users){
          foreach my $uid (keys %{$h}) {
          my $selected = ($uid == ($form->{owner} || $task->owner)) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    print qq{<option value="$uid" $selected>$h->{$uid}</option>};
    }
    }
    %>
</select>
```

and I wanted to move it into a function like this:

```
<script>
  // code...
</script>
```

Im pretty newbie with javascript and I also don't know if Perl variables can be called the same way in javascript functions?

**edit**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#owner_sel', function() {
        if(!this.form.owner_sel.selectedIndex == 0) {
            if(this.form.state_id.value == <%= $STATE_NEW %>) {
                this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_ASSIGNED %>
            }
        } else {
            this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_NEW %>
        }
    });
    $(document).on('change', '#state_id', function() {
        if (this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_NEW %> ){
            this.form.owner_sel.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    });
</script>
```

**----------Question-----------**

I redid my code to something like that. When it is just one function, everything works but when I have both scripts included like the snippet above, there is an error.

I was wondering, in my second function if the `state_id` = 'NEW' and the `owner_sel` changes to index '0' does that re-trigger the first function?

Comment: Could you please given an example of the document into which you want the template to result?

Comment: I tried making the changes myself and the functions work when they are separate but when both functions are together, there is an error where the 'states' can't be changed manually. I edited the question at the bottom.

Comment: If `$STATE_NEW` and `$STATE_ASSIGNED` are strings, you're not quoting them.

Comment: They are strings, they worked when I didn't quote them but I went ahead and quoted them anyways since it made sense to. However I'm still getting the same error conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#owner_sel', function() {
        if(!this.form.owner_sel.selectedIndex == 0) {
            if(this.form.state_id.value == <%= $STATE_NEW %>) {
                this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_ASSIGNED %>
            }
        } else {
            this.form.state_id.value = <%= $STATE_NEW %>
        }
    });
    $(document).on('change', '#state_id', function() {
        if (this.form.state_id.value == <%= $STATE_NEW %> ){
            this.form.owner_sel.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The way you translated it was correct. And yes, Perl variables can be called into the javascript function the same way you called on them inline.

The reason your code is conflicting is because your second line of code in the `.on('change', '#state_id'` code is using a single '=' and I think you meant to use '==' to check if the state is 'NEW'. The way you have it now would just change the `owner_sel.selectedIndex` to '0' everytime the `state_id` is changed.

```
if (this.form.state_id.value == <%= $STATE_NEW %> ){
```